# Extension ubuntu dock is missing

Tags: software-center, gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock, gnome-shell-extension

My extension Ubuntu dock is missing after I installed the 'Dash to Dock' extension:
[image: the ubuntu dock is missing]

When I try to install it from extensions.gnome.org it won't install. If I install it from Ubuntu Software, it will have an error as shown below:

> Unable to install "Ubuntu Dock":
>   GDBus.Error:org.gnome.Shell.CantlnstallError: This is an
>   extension enabled by your current mode, you can't install
>   manually any update in that session.

[image]

Comment: still no solution?